# nf-core/rnaseq not running deseq2 analysis

Tags: nextflow, rna-seq

i'm running the nf-core/rnaseq pipeline and it finished ok, but it doesn't do the deseq2 comparisons or pca plots. I've used version 3.5 and 3.10.1 of the pieline and neither do the differential analysis. I'm using Hisat2,  is this differential analysis only for salmon?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; Use `--pseudo_aligner salmon` option to run [DESeq2](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.10.1/docs/output.md#deseq2) in addition to `--aligner hisat2`.

Assuming you don't use the `--skip_qc` or `--skip_deseq2_qc` options, nf-core/rnaseq [v3.10.1](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/releases/tag/3.10.1) will only perform a differential expression analysis using [DESeq2](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.10.1/docs/output.md#deseq2) if using `--aligner star_salmon`<sup>[1](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.10.1/workflows/rnaseq.nf#L343-L464)</sup> (which is the default aligner) or using `--aligner star_rsem`<sup>[2](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.10.1/workflows/rnaseq.nf#L466-L497)</sup>. DESeq2 is not run when when `--aligner hisat2`<sup>[3](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.10.1/workflows/rnaseq.nf#L499-L539)</sup> is used alone. You can, however, run DESeq2 by specifying the `--pseudo_aligner salmon` option to run DESeq2<sup>[4](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/blob/3.10.1/workflows/rnaseq.nf#L760-L788)</sup>. This option runs in addition to `--aligner`.